# wget, curl commands accept partial filenames

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a file **hpraid.tar.gz** from a remote server using

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar

curl -O http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar
```

Even though the **.gz** extension is omitted in the filename part, yet the file gets downloaded by both **wget** and **curl**
This partial filename match without any wildcard baffles me.

Is there anyway I can force **wget** and **curl** to match the complete filename?

Comment: Is the file that you get through those commands compressed or not? I know that some FTP servers are able to generate archives and compressed archives of directories when accessed with a directory name ending in either `.tar` or `.tar.gz`, and the HTTP server that you're accessing may do something similar. (just speculation).

Comment: `curl -o hpraid.tar.gz http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar`

Comment: @RoVo, I would need the exact file(name) in the server to be downloaded (i.e) hpraid.tar.gz without any short name. Nothing more and nothing less otherwise my automation script would fail.

Comment: Then why not `curl -O http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar.gz` ? I somehow feel like this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: IMHO, it is not a _client_ decision. It'd be the server that _serves_ the file on _incomplete_ request too. Can you try `curl -v -O http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar` and show us the standard output?

Comment: Got a workaround options `-r` and `--accept`. Now the command `wget --no-check-certificate -r --accept="hpraid.tar.gz" http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl -v telnet://xx.xx.xx:80/` and test if the server is the one expanding `hpraid.tar` to `hpraid.tar.gz`.

#### Example

The following illustrates how we can use `curl` interactively. Here we're requesting the following URL directly from the server `GET /`.

```
$ curl -svLI telnet://www.google.com:80/ <<< "GET /" | head -5
*   Trying 74.125.141.99...
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.141.99) port 80 (#0)
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 19:39:10 GMT
Expires: -1
```

**NOTE:** Above we can see that we sent a `GET /` to Google and it responded with a STATUS 200.

#### Your issue

To verify that the server is doing the addition of the file extension `.gz` you can do something like this to verify it yourself:

```
$ curl -v telnet://xx.xx.xx.xx/hbraid.tar <<< "GET /"
```

If you see your file downloading then you know that the server is doing the appending. If it fails, then you know it's the client doing it (`curl` or `wget`).

#### Manually?

If you run into any issues with the above, you can do this all manually like so:

1. `curl` server's HTTP port

   ```
   $ curl -svLI telnet://www.google.com:80/
   *   Trying 74.125.141.99...
   * Connected to www.google.com (74.125.141.99) port 80 (#0)
   ```
2. Get URL

   ```
   GET / <--- hit Return after this 2 times!
   ```
3. Visually verify download

#### Additional tools

You can do something similar using `socat` or `nc` as well.